# Execute JavaScript [ContextMenu Chrome]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, browser-action

I'm trying to run a JavaScript code "Bookmarklet"
But I could not do it, someone knows how to do it?

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "sc-dl.js"})
});

var executeScript = function(info, tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"sc-dl.js"});
}
var Test2 = {"title": "Test2", "contexts":["page"], "parentId":menu,"onclick":executeScript};
chrome.contextMenus.create(Test2);
```

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
"web_accessible_resources": ["sc-dl.js"],
"permissions": ["contextMenus","tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"],
```

This is [the file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duncanbeevers/2157987/raw/e58d8bc51cb78f00c67670d1e93997aa2ea956e9/sc-dl.js) you want to run from a "ContextMenu" or "browserAction"

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code you're trying to inject, you'll see that it's not plain JS, and requires a whole bunch of other libraries.

You can inject them all first, but considering this was a bookmarklet, it was probably intended to be executed in a context of a certain page.

Chrome's content scripts live in an isolated context, so you should try [injecting into the page's context instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879). If it has all the libraries loaded already, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering ^ ^ 
Then, the most appropriate method would be 2 "Method 2b: Using a function" ?